# Mounted volume size in pod is smaller than size declared in PVC

Tags: database, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, mounted-volumes

I'm trying to deploy a [MongoDB Bitnami helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb) that uses a pre-existing PVC for storage in my DigitalOcean Managed Kubernetes cluster.

Everything deploys successfully -- but my pod runs out of storage space after a couple hours of operation.

I ssh'd into the pod and ran the `df -h` command

```
root@pvc-accessor-75f85f4674-29jf8:/# df -h
Filesystem                                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                                          158G   18G  134G  12% /
tmpfs                                             64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_mongodb-listing  368M  333M     0 100% /bitnami/mongodb
/dev/vda1                                        158G   18G  134G  12% /etc/hosts
shm                                               64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                            6.6G   12K  6.6G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                                            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/firmware
```

I see my mounted volume has run out of space. My PVC is 20Gi in size, why does my pod's filesystem only see 368M? I've followed [this DigitalOcean guide](https://github.com/digitalocean/csi-digitalocean/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/pod-single-existing-volume) to create the PV and PVC.

I've tried to deploy the chart without specifying a pre-existing PVC, letting the PV and PVC deploy its own. Now when I ssh into pod and run `df -h`:

```
I have no name!@mongodb-listing-7d8c8f4b5b-5b5c6:/$ df -h
Filesystem                                                                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                                                                   158G   16G  136G  11% /
tmpfs                                                                      64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_pvc-776ffcbc-8d0b-4156-8a4d-6e20fa5a90e0  7.8G  329M  7.1G   5% /bitnami/mongodb
/dev/vda1                                                                 158G   16G  136G  11% /etc/hosts
shm                                                                        64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                                     6.6G   12K  6.6G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                                                                     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                                                     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/firmware
```

The size is correct here (~8Gi, which is the chart's default).

I also [compared the PV, PVC and Pod definitions](https://www.diffchecker.com/yqPTK7Tz) and they pretty much look the same, apart from a couple of irrelevant values.

Note that the exact same issue happens if I try to deploy a [Postgres](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql) chart with a pre-existing PV and PVC.

I would appreciate any help.

Here's the YAML output of all relevant resources deployed by the MongoDB chart:

PV

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-26T21:28:59Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  - external-attacher/dobs-csi-digitalocean-com
  name: mongodb-listing-pv
  resourceVersion: "1004971"
  uid: 85960649-47cc-4c61-9bfb-a291b966fc8c
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: mongodb-listing-pvc
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "1004839"
    uid: 4e7d8427-d165-4f5e-8a94-cdb250875529
  csi:
    driver: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
    fsType: ext4
    volumeAttributes:
      com.digitalocean.csi/noformat: "true"
    volumeHandle: 0bb18717-38ba-11ed-a3a1-0a58ac14e4bf
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Bound
```

PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-26T21:29:00Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: mongodb-listing-pvc
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1005804"
  uid: 4e7d8427-d165-4f5e-8a94-cdb250875529
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: mongodb-listing-pv
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  phase: Bound
```

Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: mongodb-listing
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-26T18:18:24Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: mongodb-listing
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb-listing
    helm.sh/chart: mongodb-13.1.4
  name: mongodb-listing
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "959298"
  uid: e4b1ba11-859b-498b-bc8f-8cfd23da7482
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: mongodb-listing
      app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb-listing
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: mongodb-listing
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb-listing
        helm.sh/chart: mongodb-13.1.4
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance: mongodb-listing
                  app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb-listing
              namespaces:
              - default
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            weight: 1
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
          value: "false"
        - name: MONGODB_EXTRA_USERNAMES
          value: godard
        - name: MONGODB_EXTRA_DATABASES
          value: production
        - name: MONGODB_EXTRA_PASSWORDS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: mongodb-passwords
              name: mongodb-listing
        - name: MONGODB_ROOT_USER
          value: root
        - name: MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: mongodb-root-password
              name: mongodb-listing
        - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_SYSTEM_LOG_VERBOSITY
          value: "0"
        - name: MONGODB_DISABLE_SYSTEM_LOG
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_DISABLE_JAVASCRIPT
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_ENABLE_JOURNAL
          value: "yes"
        - name: MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER
          value: "27017"
        - name: MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_EXTRA_FLAGS
          value: --setParameter diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled=false
        image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:6.0.1-debian-11-r11
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bitnami/scripts/ping-mongodb.sh
          failureThreshold: 6
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 20
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        name: mongodb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: mongodb
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bitnami/scripts/readiness-probe.sh
          failureThreshold: 6
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1001
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/mongodb
          name: datadir
        - mountPath: /bitnami/scripts
          name: common-scripts
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - args:
        - -ec
        - |
          mkdir -p /bitnami/mongodb/
          chown 1001:1001 /bitnami/mongodb/
          find  /bitnami/mongodb/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name ".snapshot" -not -name "lost+found" | xargs -r chown -R 1001:1001
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        image: docker.io/bitnami/bitnami-shell:11-debian-11-r36
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: volume-permissions
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/mongodb
          name: datadir
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      serviceAccount: mongodb-listing
      serviceAccountName: mongodb-listing
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 360
          name: mongodb-listing-common-scripts
        name: common-scripts
      - name: datadir
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongodb-listing-pvc
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-26T18:18:24Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-09-26T18:18:24Z"
    message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
    status: "False"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-26T18:28:25Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-09-26T18:28:25Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "mongodb-listing-69fbf5599c" has timed out progressing.
    reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
    status: "False"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

StorageClass

```
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-24T03:19:00Z"
  labels:
    c3.doks.digitalocean.com/component: csi-controller-service
    c3.doks.digitalocean.com/plane: data
    doks.digitalocean.com/managed: "true"
  name: do-block-storage
  resourceVersion: "843720"
  uid: eae501c9-1a66-46d2-adfb-c3c430213908
provisioner: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Link to my reddit post about this (to view other comment threads): https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/xorlk6/mounted_volume_size_in_pod_is_smaller_than_size/

Comment: `volumeHandle: 0bb18717-38ba-11ed-a3a1-0a58ac14e4bf` - what is the actual size of this volume?

Comment: @gohm'c It's 20GiB. Output from `doctl compute volume list`:

ID/Name/Size/Region/Filesystem Type/Filesystem Label/Droplet IDs
0bb18717-38ba-11ed-a3a1-0a58ac14e4bf/mongodb-listing/20 GiB/tor1/ext4/[318033244]

Comment: [This](https://github.com/digitalocean/csi-digitalocean/issues/175) may help. You may need to clarify directly with DO about the limitation.

Comment: @gohm'c Thank you so much for bringing this to my attention. It is the exact problem I'm facing. Looks like I will have to remove the PV/PVC definitions from my Terraform project and let the deployment handle it.